# PHP insert $key => $value into an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a programming assignment to add values to a PHP array after I validate that their either ints, floats, or strings.

I need to take the contents of the `$products` array and only insert them into the `$inventory` array if the data meets those conditions.

This is my source array:

```
$products = [
    [

        'item_number' => 15678,
        'description' => 'Tophat',
        'size' => 'small',
        'shelf' => 5,
        'aisle' => 12,
        'quantity' => 10,
        'price' => 5.99
    ],
    [

        'item_number' => 15662,
        'description' => 'T-shirt',
        'size' => 'large',
        'shelf' => 9,
        'aisle' => 13,
        'quantity' => 15,
        'price' => null
    ]
];
```

This is my validation function:

```
{
foreach ($product as $value) {
    if (!is_int($value) && !is_string($value) && !is_float($value)){
        return false;
    }
return true;
}
```

And this is the function that adds the `$products` to the `$inventory` array:

```
function create_inventory(array $products) : array
{
    $inventory = [];
    foreach ($products as $product)
    {
       if (is_valid($product)){
           foreach ($product as $value) {
               $inventory[] = $value;
           }
       }
    }
    return $inventory;
}
```

This works and only the `Tophat` is added to the `$inventory` array because the `T-shirt` product has a `null` value. The output looks like this:

```
0 : 15678
1 : Tophat
2 : small
3 : 5
4 : 12
5 : 10
6 : 5.99
```

But now I want to add the keys to the `$inventory` array, not just the values. I would like the output from the `$inventory` array to look like this:

```
item_number : 15678
description : Tophat
size : small
shelf : 5
aisle : 12
quantity : 10
price : $5.99
```

This is the full version of my script: [store_inventory.php](https://github.com/bluethundr/learn_php_8/blob/main/Chapter%203/store_inventory.php)

I've tried a few things that haven't worked. How can I add both the `$key` and the `$value` to the `$inventory` array?

Comment: In your foreach loop you can access the keys like so `foreach ($product as $key=>$value) `

Comment: Thanks, I've tried that but what I need to know is how to insert them into the `$inventory` array.

Comment: I would actually just do this: `$inventory[] = $product;`, no need to loop through the values

Comment: That didn't work. Instead of looping I just used `$inventory[] = $product` and this was the result: `0 : Array` This is the code I used: `if (is_valid($product)){$inventory[] = $product; }`

Comment: If you get lost in a foreach round an array, just `print_r($value)`  to see what you are really processing

Comment: `print_r($product)` shows me the complete contents of the array: `Array ( [item_number] => 15678 [description] => Tophat [size] => small [shelf] => 5 [aisle] => 12 [quantity] => 10 [price] => 5.99 )`. Yet when I assign the product to inventory like `$inventory[] = $prodcuct;` I get the strange output of: `0 : Array`.  However if I loop through the array I can get all the values, but the keys are missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the comments, you can loop over an array keys and values using:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value)
```

If there are no keys the index of the array is the key.

Now for you question, you can use this kind of loop to fill you `$inventory`. Another problem in your code is that if you have more than one valid product, it will override the previous valid product. In order to solve this, you could put all your valid products inside arrays in the inventory array. Here's how:

```
function create_inventory(array $products): array
{
    $inventory = [];
    // loop over your product array using the index to create an array if the product is valid.
    foreach ($products as $index => $product) {
        if (is_valid($product)) {
            // Create an empty array when the product is valid.
            $inventory[$index] = [];
            // Loop over the product values and add them to the newly created array.
            foreach ($product as $key => $value) {
                $inventory[$index][$key] = $value;
            }
        }
    }
    return $inventory;
}
```

If you prefer, see this [interactive example](https://3v4l.org/LXtKG).

Comment: Thank you. If I try your version of the function, I get this output: `0 : Array
1 : Array
2 : Array` This is the full script as I have it: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bluethundr/learn_php_8/main/Chapter%203/store_inventory.php

Comment: That has to do with how you are printing the values. You must loop within your loop to get each of the values.

Comment: Thank you! That worked perfectly. Here's my code in case you're interested: https://github.com/bluethundr/learn_php_8/blob/main/Chapter%203/store_inventory.php

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the key along with the value:

```
1. Your foreach needs to be like this: foreach($products as $key => $value)
2. Then you add to the array like this: $inventory[$key] = $value;
```

Your validate function seems to never be called?  It doesn't even have a function name.

**EDIT:**

Since your products array is an array of arrays.  This code will do what you want, without validation.

```
foreach($products as $item)
{
 foreach($item as $key => $value)
 {
  echo("{$key} - {$value}" . PHP_EOL);
 }
}
```

**2nd EDIT:**

You need to do something like this:

```
$inventory[count($inventory) - 1][$key] = $value;
```

Or:

```
foreach($products as $row => $item)
{
 foreach($item as $key => $value)
 {
  $inventory[$row][$key] = $value
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That assignment works to get me the keys and values. However a new problem is that if I have multiple items in the `$products` array, it only prints out the last valid item in the array. This is the output: `number : 10005342
description : Shorts
size : large
shelf : 4
aisle : 13
quantity : 24
price : 9.99` It seems that each item is replacing the previous one. How can I get around that?

Comment: @bluethundr, see my 2nd edit above.  Since it is an array of arrays you need an array for each array.  Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

```
$products = [
        [
    
            'item_number' => 15678,
            'description' => 'Tophat',
            'size' => 'small',
            'shelf' => 5,
            'aisle' => 12,
            'quantity' => 10,
            'price' => 5.99
        ],
        [
    
            'item_number' => 15662,
            'description' => 'T-shirt',
            'size' => 'large',
            'shelf' => 9,
            'aisle' => 13,
            'quantity' => 15,
            'price' => null
        ]
    ];
    
    
    
        function createInventory($theProducts){
            $inventory=[];
            foreach ($theProducts as $value) {
                if (!is_int($value) && !is_string($value) && !is_float($value)){
                    foreach ($value as $key => $item) {
                        $inventory[$key] = $item;
                    }
                }
            }
    
            return $inventory;
        }
```

From how I understand the question I think It should be this way as it return the $inventory array with both the key and the value